# Does verifying interactions in unit tests break encapsulation?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

As i'm learning more about unit testing i've come to realize the behavior (interaction) vs. state verification approaches that are well known in this field.

Verifying **the state** of some system after performing a certain operation seems logical to me.

Can the same be said about verifying the interaction of the class under test with some other component? i am still not 100% convinced.

For example:

```
public void DoSomething(IDependency dependency)
{
    // some code ...

    dependency.Method();

    dependency.Method2();

    // some more code ...
}
```

Does the fact that current implementation of DoSomething() call Method() and Method2() and is testable using mocks have any real value?

**Isn't the calling of these 2 methods an implementation detail of the DoSomething() ?**

It seems that verifying interactions is a lot more fragile when compared to state based verification, and also breaks encapsulation (testing something that is hidden by this method).

Comment: It depends on _what_ you are testing. If you are testing the _interactions_, than this is fine. If you are testing something else... probably no.

Comment: I'd say that the ordering of method calls should be tested only if the public interface defines a set order to call them. i.e. "Open before Read" or something similar. In this case, using a mock-up of the interface to thest the method might be a good idea, but it boils down to: "where do you draw the line with your test code?"

Answer (score 3):

If a specification (some call it test) requires that a certain kind of interaction takes place, you should also verify that this is the case and have a unit test for this. For example if it is required that the SUT saves a file, you should probably verify that `IFileSystem.Save(...)` has been called. And if is required that the SUT should safe it with a new filename if the file exists you should verify that `IFileSystem.Save(...)` has been called with the right filename and that `IFileSystem.Exists(...)` has been called. This is interaction testing at its best.

Using [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) it would look something like this:

```
// arrange
var fileSystem = A.Fake<IFileSystem>();
A.CallTo(() => fileSystem.Exists("file.txt")).Returns(true);
A.CallTo(() => fileSystem.Exists("file1.txt")).Returns(false);
var sut = new SystemUnderTest(fileSystem);

// act
sut.DoSomething(); // do something that eventually saves file.txt

// assert
A.CallTo(() => fileSystem.Exists("file.txt")).MustHaveHappened();
A.CallTo(() => fileSystem.Exists("file1.txt")).MustHaveHappened();
A.CallTo(() => fileSystem.Save("file1.txt")).MustHaveHappened();
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, well, if you want to verify the behavior of `DoSomething(IDependency dependency)` I'd say that you definitely want to verify that your dependencies are called.

That's what mocks are typically for. You want to be sure that your dependency is correctly dealt with in your `SuT`. You don't want to be bothered with implementation details of your dependencies.

So I nice test would be something like:

```
[Test]
public void DoSomething()
{
    var sut = new Whatever();
    var dependencyMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDependency>();
    dependencyMock.Stub(() => mock.Method1()).Repeat = 1;
    dependencyMock.Stub(() => mock.Method2()).Repeat = 1;
    sut.DoSomething(dependencyMock);

    // verify that expected methods are being called
    dependencyMock.VerifyAllExpectations(); 

    // make some meaningful assert for sut.
    Assert. // ... etc
}
```

Note that I typed this without studio open, so all that modulo typos modulo bugs :). Just to give you an idea.

---

If you are only 'glueing' functionality together. Like a class does nothing else then call method on dependency objects, you it might be worthwhile to investigate if you should refactor that 'code smell'. But in the example you provided above, I'd say you got it all right, and you should go for it.